# AMD Driver Error on Ubuntu 22.04

Tags: drivers, kernel, display-resolution, gpu

So I am trying to follow this guide for stable diffusion on an amd card:
https://www.reddit.com/r/StableDiffusion/comments/zu9w40/novices_guide_to_automatic1111_on_linux_with_amd/

**FYI I have a 7900XT**

It doesn't matter if you know what stable diffusion is or not, the thing I am having trouble with is the amd driver install / rocm install. I have been trying for the past 12 hours to get this thing installed. This is my second try since I corrupted linux last time.

After using the command:
`sudo amdgpu-install --usecase=rocm --no-dkms` to install it without kernel drivers it reverts back to how ubuntu was for me when it was first installed, like the drivers disappeared.

To give you context, when I installed ubuntu the resolution and hertz were locked at like 1024x768 and 60hz, which was really weird but after some digging around for a bit it turned out I hade to update my linux kernel because the kernel that came with ubuntu didn't initially work with my graphics card, the 7900XT. I installed this kernel:
[https://kernel.ubuntu.com/~kernel-ppa/mainline/v6.1.21/amd64/](https://kernel.ubuntu.com/%7Ekernel-ppa/mainline/v6.1.21/amd64/)

Then it worked fine and it detected my gpu. However after using the aforementioned command (amd-gpu install yadi yada yada) it has now reverted back to having my resolution and refresh rate locked and xrandr gives the gamma error and when I try to use rocminfo which I literally just installed it gives this error:
ROCk module is NOT loaded, possibly no GPU devices

What could be causing this? At this stage a reboot bricked my linux last time so I don't know what to do. I am new to linux so if you need some more info to troubleshoot my issue then please tell me because I don't know what is needed.

Comment: That kernel is not supported by Ubuntu and rc means that it is not even the final of the kernel. They are still working on it. As it is not a supported kernel it is off-topic on this site.

Comment: I changed it to kernel version 6.1.21, the issue still persists.